# Проблема в обработчике нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview.adapter, android-on-click

Недавно начал изучать разработку на android. Появилась проблема в обработчике нажатия кнопки.
В фрагменте есть 2 `RecyclerView`, для каждого свой адаптер. 1-й адаптер с категориями, 2-й с самим товаром.

В адаптере я сделал такую обработку

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.categoryButton.setText(categories.get(position).getTitle());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                HomeFragment.showMenuByCategory(categories.get(position).getId());
            }
        });
    }
```

В `HomeFragment` объявлена переменная `ids`, с типом данных `String`.
И в этом же фрагменте написал такую функцию

```
    public static void showMenuByCategory(int id){

        ids = String.valueOf(id);

        menuKitchen.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

И далее в другом адаптере:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull MyViewClass holder, int position) {
        if(ids == "0"){
            holder.title.setText(title.get(position));
            holder.des.setText(des.get(position));
            Picasso.get().load(image.get(position)).into(holder.img);
            holder.price.setText(price.get(position));
        }else{
            for(String i : category){
                if(ids == i){
                    holder.title.setText(title.get(position));
                    holder.des.setText(des.get(position));
                    Picasso.get().load(image.get(position)).into(holder.img);
                    holder.price.setText(price.get(position));
                }
            }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

В массиве `category`, находятся все категории, полученные из json-массива.

Проблема в том, что нет никакой реакции на нажатие кнопок. И если, я в переменную `ids` помещу "0", то все элементы выведутся как надо. А если другое число, то выводится ничего не будет.

Массив в котором находятся все категории(Написан в `HomeFragment` и передаётся в адаптер)

```
        categoryList.add(new Category(1, "Всё"));
        categoryList.add(new Category(2, "Мясо"));
        categoryList.add(new Category(3, "Рыба"));
        categoryList.add(new Category(4, "Бургеры"));
        categoryList.add(new Category(5, "Салаты"));
        categoryList.add(new Category(6, "Закуски"));
``

После нескольких часов лазанья по гуглу к решению не пришел...
Как можно решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо!
```

Comment: метку android-studio следует использовать в вопросах связанных непосредственно с IDE

Comment: Если у вас ids строка то так строки не сравнивают == "0".